# Opening vivaldi opens sometimes in the same workspace but not always

Tags: bash, workspaces, vivaldi

I am new here and also new to Unix. I have Ubuntu 18.04

I am about to create a shell later so that I can just click on the file for opening multiple applications for one of my Workspace (1)

For the moment I have just tried to do the commands in the terminal

`vivaldi &vivaldi url1 &vivaldi url2 &vivaldi url3`

The problem is that when I hit enter, it opens these windows on my workspace 0 while i am active on my workspace 1.

However sometimes it opens on my existing workspace 1. Mostly it doesn't. So I am confused why.

Anyone who can help? Is there any way to force it to open on my active workspace?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason it jumps to my other workspace is because i have tabs opened there allready. So it continues to open there.

Anyways.i made this with Wmctrl:

## !/bin/bash

wmctrl -s 1 #Switches to workspace 1 [workspaces are numbered from 0]
&vivaldi url1 &vivaldi url2 &vivaldi url3 & #Opens tabs with specific urls.

The problem is that if i have vivaldi allready opened at workspace 0 and not in workspace 1, then this script creates those tabs in workspace 0.

To start a new instance of Vivaldi in workspace 1 i can however use Ctrl+n. And then off course run the script.

So how can i enter the shortcut "Ctrl + n" into this script?

Thanks